# Multiple inheritance in Python and constructor

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I am in the process of learning python and learning classes and objects. I have a doubt regarding this code

```
class machine(object):
    def __init__(self,processor):
        print "I am in constructor of machine class"
        print processor

class computer(machine):
    def __init__(self,name,processor):
        print "I am in constructor of computer class"
        super(computer,self).__init__(processor)
        print name,
        print processor

class laptop(machine):
    def __init__(self,name,processor):
        print "I am in constructor of laptop class"
        super(laptop,self).__init__(processor)
        print name,
        print processor

class respbarry(computer,laptop):
    def __init__(self,name,processor):
        print "I am in constructor of respbarry class"
        super(respbarry,self).__init__(name,processor)
        print name,
        print processor

m = machine("P4")
c = computer("Computer","P4")
l = laptop("Laptop","P4")
r = respbarry("Respbarry","P4")
```

Now doing above what error I am getting is

```
I am in constructor of machine class 
P4
I am in constructor of computer class
I am in constructor of machine class 
P4
Computer P4
I am in constructor of laptop class
I am in constructor of machine class 
P4
Laptop P4
I am in constructor of respbarry class
I am in constructor of computer class
```

So when I call machine class I am getting machine constructor of machine call then I call computer class constructor then laptop class constructor. Everything is fine till now but in respbarry constructor I am getting error? I think machine class constructor should be 2 time in respbarry but I am getting error 
    `TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)`

Comment: In this context, [this presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EiOglTERPEo) may prove useful. Your classes must all accept the same arguments if you want to use cooperative subclassing with multiple inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `print respbarry.mro()` output:

```
[<class '__main__.respbarry'>, <class '__main__.computer'>, <class '__main__.laptop'>, <class '__main__.machine'>, <type 'object'>]
```

In multiple inheritance after linerization `super(computer,self).__init__(...)` will call `laptop` constructor.
That's why you get this error.

That is a feature of Python which allows to change the behavior of an object adding a new class into inheritance chain.

Take a look at https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/335045/raymond_hettinger_super_considered_super_pycon/

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing different parameters to a method being called via super, all the implementations of that method going up the MRO towards `object()` need to have compatible signatures. The `__init__` method is no exception.
Add an additional `**kwargs` parameter to each of your base class constructors and that error will disappear.

The definition of the `machine` class should look like this:

```
class machine(object):
    def __init__(self, processor, **kwargs):
        print "I am in constructor of machine class"
        print processor


class computer(machine):
    def __init__(self, name, processor):
        print "I am in constructor of computer class"
        super(computer,self).__init__(name=name, processor=processor)
        print name,
        print processor


class laptop(machine):
    def __init__(self, name, processor):
        print "I am in constructor of laptop class"
        super(laptop,self).__init__(name=name, processor=processor)
        print name,
        print processor

class respbarry(computer,laptop):
    def __init__(self, name, processor):
        print "I am in constructor of respbarry class"
        super(respbarry,self).__init__(name=name,processor=processor)
        print name,
        print processor
```

Comment: @geeksoul: MRO = Method Resolution Order

Comment: how? to add the **kawargs. Sorry I am not getting this?

Comment: Sorry, I edited my answer with a code snippet.

Comment: I edited it again to make it more clear how to deal with that `**kwargs` argument in the base class.